# Compiling git: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, git

I've got a Pi2 running Raspbian Wheezy, and I'm trying to build git 2.8.1 from source (because the binary packages are something ancient like 1.7). It compiles and installs, but I'm apparently missing something for SSL, because I get this when I try cloning a repository:

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I have libcurl4-openssl-dev and libssl-dev installed; what else do I need to make this work?

Comment: git is an old version partly because you are running an old OS that is no longer supported. Upgrading to Jessie will install git 2.1.4

Comment: Ditto.  If you continue on this way, you will one by one end up having to build all the components of the system you consider significant as they become outdated.  Jessie became the stable version of Rasbian about a year ago and wheezy will no longer be updated (except, possibly, for security patches, but that will end eventually too).

Answer (score 1):

Git is an old version partly because you are running an old OS that is no longer supported. Upgrading to Jessie will install git 2.1.4.

Alternatively, it appears based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https), that installing libcurl4-openssl-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

will fix the problem.

Comment: Got a link to a straightforward upgrade process? Jessie went stable/mainstream sometime last fall, and I got the Pi2 and installed Wheezy a month or two prior to that. I haven't looked lately, but back when it was released, it seemed like the process involved a lot of manual steps, and fixing things afterward. (Also, git 2.1.4 is from Dec. 2014, so I'd be building my own anyway.)

Comment: I avoided the upgrade process and just created a new SD Card, This was easy since I manage my Pi's with puppet.

Comment: Well, I don't fancy reinstalling/reconfiguring Apache, bind, znc, samba, fail2ban, cups, postfix, the hardware RTC module and RNG, scheduled maintenance jobs, and whatever else I've forgotten is on there now, so I'll probably stay on Wheezy until there's an upgrade process better than "nuke it and start over". It's still getting package updates, at least.